# Magento - local.xml not recognising customer_logged_out

Tags: magento

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2 and would like to show some links only when the customer is logged out.

If I add the below code to local.xml nothing happens (I am logged out):

```
 <customer_logged_out>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Test</label><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/><title>Test</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
        </reference>
        <remove name="reorder"></remove>
</customer_logged_out>
```

However as soon as I remove the customer_logged_out tags the link gets displayed (for everyone) ie:

```
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Test</label><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/><title>Test</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
    </reference>
    <remove name="reorder"></remove>
```

If I try to use customer_logged_in tags nothing gets displayed also.

Why are these logged_in/logged_out tags not working in local.xml?

Comment: As Alan says, it sounds like you have the <customer_logged_out> node nested inside another layout handle.

Comment: Thanks!  You were both correct.  Once I moved the code outside of the <default> tags it worked.